# Permission denied to github-actions[bot] despite having PAT

Tags: git, github, github-actions, workflow

I am trying to build a github actions workflow that runs a python script to make some changes to certain files in the repo, then pushes those changes to a different repo. Essentially, the end goal is to have two repos, one that is the normal version that everybody pushes to, and a second that is a slightly tweaked mirror of that repo that nobody ever has to manually deal with.

The following is my workflow yaml file. I have uploaded a personal access token to the repo in question under the secrets tab and named it "STUDENT_BOOK_TOKEN". It has read/write access to repo content for the second repository (and the repo it is running in, even though it shouldn't need that?)

```
name: Clean

on:
  push:
    paths:
      - 'book/**'
      - '.github/workflows/clean.yaml'
      - '.github/actions/**'

    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04

    steps:
    - name: Checkout repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
      with:
        token: ${{ secrets.STUDENT_BOOK_TOKEN }}

    - uses: ./.github/actions/studentversion
      with:
        token: ${{ secrets.STUDENT_BOOK_TOKEN }}
```

This code triggers the following github action successfully, which is able to run and make the necessary changes to some files. However, it fails on the last step, namely the one that uses `ad-m/github-push-action@v0.6.0`. However, the only error message github will give me is that a 403 was returned, which isn't much to go off of.

```
name: 'Create Student Version'
description: 'Run book cleaning script and push to student version repo'

inputs:
  token:
    description: 'A GitHub Personal Access Token (for publishing)'
    required: true

runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:

    - name: checkout repo content
      uses: actions/checkout@v3 # checkout the repository content to github runner

    - name: setup python
      uses: actions/setup-python@v4
      with:
        python-version: '3.9' # install the python version needed
        
    - name: install python packages
      shell: bash
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install pyyaml
        
    - name: execute py script # run clean_book.py
      shell: bash
      run: python .github/workflows/clean_book.py
        
    - name: remove book cleaning workflow # no need to run it on the student version, since we handled it already
      uses: JesseTG/rm@v1.0.3
      with:
        path: .github/workflows/clean.yaml

    - name: commit files
      shell: bash
      run: |
        git config --local user.email "action@github.com"
        git config --local user.name "GitHub Action"
        git add -a
        git commit -a -m "cleaned books for student version" --allow-empty

    - name: push changes
      uses: ad-m/github-push-action@v0.6.0
      with:
        github_token: ${{ inputs.token }}
        repository: geo-smart/curriculum-book-student
        branch: main 
        force: true
```

This is the exact output I see, in case that helps. I found [this](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/26694) promising thread with what appears to be the same issue at surface level, but the accepted solution did not work (as can be seen in the workflow yaml file, where it is implemented to no avail).

[image: workflow logs]

I imagine this information is unlikely to be enough to solve my issue, but any pointers in a direction to explore would be greatly appreciated. The top 10 or so related issues I can find googling for this are all dead ends, and without github giving me more information than a simple 403 I've kind of hit a wall.

Comment: You use the same token `secrets.STUDENT_BOOK_TOKEN` both for checking out the current repository and pushing to a different repo. Shouldn't these be 2 different tokens? One token per repo? Also make sure the 2nd token was created with write-access to the repo.

Comment: @phd I only added the secrets.STUDENT_BOOK_TOKEN for checking out the current repository as per the linked thread, it is a public repo and can pull without that line. I can try splitting to have two separate tokens though. 

Just double checked on the PAT and it has: "Read and Write access to actions, code, commit statuses, secrets, and workflows"

Comment: You also use it to push: you pass the token to `uses: ./.github/actions/studentversion` where it's used in `uses: ad-m/github-push-action@v0.6.0` to push to a (AFAIU) different repo `geo-smart/curriculum-book-student`. My advise is: checkout without an explicit token; it's not required even for a private repository as Github Actions create a temporary transient token to access the source repo; by default you can even push back to the source repo but that can be controlled in repo settings. As for pushing to a different repo — create a PAT scoped for that repo.

Comment: @pdh Yeah, unfortunately it would seem that using separate keys for checkout and pushing has no effect on the issue. I think at this point, considering how poor the error logging is I will likely just pivot to using SSH or something. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

Github Actions requires you to explicitly configure the `permissions`. This can be done on a per-workflow basis, or on a per-job basis.

Example on how to do this for a specific job:

```
jobs:
  update:
    name: Create a branch a PR from that branch
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    permissions:
      contents: write  # To push a branch 
      pull-requests: write  # To create a PR from that branch
```

Documentation: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/assigning-permissions-to-jobs